# Laravel Pivot Relationship not unique table/alias

Tags: laravel, pivot, relation

I have three Tables & corresponding models:

**Table** ------ **Model**

papers ------ Paper

paper_stocks ------ PaperStock

paper_stock_amounts ------ PaperStockAmount

Paper contains diff. types of paper.
PaperStock contains different places where these papers can be stored
PaperStockAmount contains the paper id, the stock id and the amount, to determine how many of paper A are in stock B.

Now I want to check outgoing from the paper how manyy are in each stock. Therefore Im doing this in my view:

```
@foreach($papers as $paper)
    @foreach($paper->paperStockAmount as $ps)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $ps->stock->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $ps->amount }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This should show every type of paper and in which stocks along with the amount they are in.

However this is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'paper_stock_amounts' (SQL: select `paper_stock_amounts`.*, `paper_stock_amounts`.`id` as `pivot_id`, `paper_stock_amounts`.`amount` as `pivot_amount` from `paper_stock_amounts` inner join `paper_stock_amounts` on `paper_stock_amounts`.`id` = `paper_stock_amounts`.`id` where `paper_stock_amounts`.`id` in (1, 2))
```

The relationships are defined like this:

**Paper**

```
class Paper extends Model
{
    public function paperStockAmount()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PaperStockAmount', 'paper_stock_amounts')->withPivot('amount');
    }
}
```

**PaperStockAmount**

```
class PaperStockAmount extends Model
{
    public function paper()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Paper', 'id', 'paper_id');
    }

    public function stock()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PaperStock', 'id', 'stock_id');
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined M-M Relationship between `paper` & `paper_stock`.

i.e. If you are fetching `paperStockAmount` from `$paper`, then you would get `paper_stock` results with the pivot column `amount`.

You should do it like this:

```
@foreach($papers as $paper)
    @foreach($paper->paperStockAmount as $paper_stock)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $paper_stock->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $paper_stock->pivot->amount }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Use `pivot` to fetch the pivot column named - `amount`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it looks your relation from `Paper` to `PaperStockAmount` is `has-many`, so your relation should be as:

Paper

```
class Paper extends Model
{
    public function paperStockAmount()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PaperStockAmount');
    }
}
```

Then your view code will work.

OR

If the relation between from `Paper` and `PaperStock` is `many-to-many` then your relation should be as:

Paper

```
class Paper extends Model
{
    public function paperStockAmount()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PaperStock', 'paper_stock_amounts')->withPivot('amount');
    }
}
```

Then in your view, it can be accessed as: (taking from @saumya answer)

```
@foreach($papers as $paper)
    @foreach($paper->paperStockAmount as $paper_stock)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $paper_stock->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $paper_stock->pivot->amount }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Appearently hasMany doesn't support Pivot. None of this is working sadly.

Comment: What's the error? And please show the table columns in your question.